# Making an app backwards compatible, problems with frameworks

Tags: macos, frameworks, crash, osx-snow-leopard

I've been having some trouble making my app backward compatible for Mac OS X 10.6 systems. I've integrated Crashlytics into the app and it works fine for Mac OS X 10.7 - 10.10 and it works just fine. However, the app also needs to be compatible with the older version of OS X 10.6 and the Crashlytics framework only supports down to 10.7.

I already fixed the first crash due to the libc++ library which did not come bundled with 10.6 by making it an optional include. It's the next crash I can't figure out: Symbol not found: _objc_release
If I completely remove all calls to Crashlytics inside the app it works just fine. However, if I include the one line which Crashlytics needs to get started: `[Fabric with:@[[Crashlytics class]]];` it will crash right after launching with `Symbol not found: _objc_release`.

The next logical step for me was to add a simple if statement to check if the system version was compatible with the framework, but the app still crashed although if I removed the Crashlytics line the if statement worked just fine!

I'm using Xcode 7, Mac OS X 10.10 with the base SDK set to 10.6.
Here is a quick example of what I have tried:

[Using the suggested way by Apple:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Using/using.html)

```
Class cls = NSClassFromString(@"Fabric");
if(!cls)
{  
  [Fabric with:@[[Crashlytics class]]];

  NSLog(@"Framework is installed!");
}
else
{
  NSLog(@"Framework is not installed!");
}
```

Comparing System version numbers:

```
if(NSAppKitVersionNumber >= NSAppKitVersionNumber10_7)
{  
  [Fabric with:@[[Crashlytics class]]];

  NSLog(@"Framework is installed!");
}
else
{
  NSLog(@"Framework is not installed!");
}
```

Am I missing something obvious here?